# Gradle несколько версий сборки android проекта

Tags: android, gradle

В ходе разработки использую `Retrofit2`.
В `Retrofit2` использую logger:

```
.client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(BODY)).build())// Logging
```

**Как мне сделать чтобы в релизной версии не было этой зависимости?**

Если в Gradle я укажу Logger'у `testImplementation` тогда мне придется закомментировать строку Logger'а.

Answer (score 4):

Например, так:

В `build.gradle` описать зависимость, как

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
```

Создать файл `src/debug/java/com/example/logging/LoggingInterceptor`:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;

import static okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY;

public class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(BODY);

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        return interceptor.intercept(chain);
    }
}
```

Создать файл `src/release/java/com/example/logging/LoggingInterceptor`:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        return chain.proceed(chain.request());
    }
}
```

И использовать этот интерсептор в проекте:

```java
.client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor()).build())// Logging
```

Тогда, при сборке `assembleDebug` будет использоваться интерсептор с логгером, а при сборке `assembleRelease` будет использоваться пустой интерсептор, а библиотека с логгером не попадет в classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Есть менее мудреный способ:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(BODY);

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
           return interceptor.intercept(chain); //в дебажной версии сработает эта ветка
        else
           return chain.proceed(chain.request()); //в релизной эта ветка
    }
}
```

Ключ переменная `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, которая в релизе `false`